# minimongo query only specific fields

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I read in http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance
that it is a good practice to specify fields you want to query from the db. It made sense in sense of speed, and in terms of reactivity.

I have a modal where I only display my course name. I don't want this modal to be rerendered everytime someone changes something about the course. So I tried to do:

Courses.findOne({}, {fields: {name: 1, admins: 0}})

But it gives me the whole object anyway (having only name: 1 or admins: 0 didn't change anything):

Object {_id: "multiplicationCourse", name: "Multiplication table", admins: Array[2], upVotes: Array[0], downVotes: Array[0]…}

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it because this course was downloaded somewhere in the code before and this is looked up from the cache not actual the db?

Or do I always get all the data that I publish on the server-side, no matter what I put in "fields" on the client side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to return specific fields in client:
http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#fieldspecifiers

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks! So... I have my course lessons nested in the course collection, and then comments to the lessons nested in the lessons. Everytime someone adds a comment, all my Courses.find() in my website will rerender? That sounds extreme...
I guess, I can publish the courses differently.

Comment: Yes. You need to think about how you may publish collections so client memory do not explode :)